# Using System.Drawing, how can I draw something that imitates the effect of a yellow highlighting marker?

Tags: .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I want what's "behind" the yellow to show through.

EDIT 1: But, if I'm drawing on "white", I'd like the marker color to retain its pure yellowness.

EDIT 2: @Kevin's answer is probably correct, and I marked it correct, even though I didn't code it up.  In my code, I'm settling for @Guffa's answer, using Color.FromArgb.

EDIT 3: I posted code that works with decent performance.  Yes, subtracting the blue is the basic idea, but you can't do it with a high level API, and SetPixel is too slow.  The solution with good performance uses Bitmap.LockBits, UnlockBits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works.  It wipes out the blue component of every RGB where I want yellow.  At first I tried using Bitmap.GetPixel/SetPixel, but that was painfully slow.  Using Lock/Unlock to get the raw bits was performed fast enough.

```
                using (Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics tempG = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap))
                    {

                        tempG.DrawLines(penYellowHighlighter, stroke.points.ToArray());

                        // get the raw bits of the source and target and remove the blue from every
                        // bit of the target where there is a yellow bit of the source
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapWithStrokes.Width, bitmapWithStrokes.Height);

                        // lock
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData sourceData =
                            tempBitmap.LockBits(
                                rect,
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                tempBitmap.PixelFormat);

                        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData targetData =
                            bitmapWithStrokes.LockBits(
                                rect,
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                bitmapWithStrokes.PixelFormat);

                        // Get the address of the first line.
                        IntPtr sourcePtr = sourceData.Scan0;
                        IntPtr targetPtr = targetData.Scan0;

                        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                        int numberOfBytes = Math.Abs(sourceData.Stride) * tempBitmap.Height;

                        byte[] sourceRgbValues = new byte[numberOfBytes];
                        byte[] targetRgbValues = new byte[numberOfBytes];

                        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(sourcePtr, sourceRgbValues, 0, numberOfBytes);
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(targetPtr, targetRgbValues, 0, numberOfBytes);

                        for (int p = 0; p < numberOfBytes; p += 4)
                        {
                            // if the source's red is yellows's red
                            if (sourceRgbValues[p + 2] == yellowsRedComponent)
                            {
                                // wipe out the target's blue
                                targetRgbValues[p] = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(targetRgbValues, 0, targetPtr, numberOfBytes);

                        // Unlock the bits.
                        tempBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);
                        bitmapWithStrokes.UnlockBits(targetData);
```

Answer (score 9):

A highlighter is pigment, so it's essentially subtractive — you want to turn white into yellow, but not black into yellow. I don't know .NET, but what you want is a non-default “blending mode”, specifically *subtract*. Specifically, set the blending mode to subtract and your color to pure *blue* (the color you want to subtract, leaving yellow). Black will be left alone, since there's no blue to subtract, and white will become yellow.

Unfortunately, many modern drawing interfaces leave out blending modes other than alpha, and it looks like this might be one of them. If you have access to the bitmap, you can implement it yourself — take each pixel value and set the blue component to zero. Or if the area you want to highlight is complicated, then: make a copy of your image, draw black over the highlighted area in the copy, then combine the red and green channels from the original and the blue channel from the copy into the final result image.

Comment: Yikes! This is beyond my level of ambition, but it's looking like your answer is the right answer if I don't want to compromise the effect, if I want the yellow to be yellow.

Comment: Well, it's very simple — just one parameter setting — *if* you have a drawing system which supports blend modes.

Comment: Is this the same thing as "color burn" in some graphics apps?  E.g., paint.net?  (Learning something new every day!  :D )

Comment: Never heard of color burn. If http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/656/1/Feel-the-Color-Burn is accurate, then it isn't the same: in that article's Example 1, using subtract mode would, firstly, have the greatest effect in the *white* areas, not the black, and secondly, would not increase the saturation of the preexisting colors, but rather make them closer to black (given that you're blending in white (goes to black) rather than blue (goes to yellow))

Comment: I've just posted code here, using Bitmap.LockBits/UnlockBits, that does the subtraction of the blue bit by bit with acceptable performance.

Answer (score 3):

You use a semi transparent color, for example with a 50% alpha opacity:

```
Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Yellow)
```

With a lower alpha value more of the background will show through.

Comment: Thanks - This works, but not quite how I had hoped.  I want the yellow itself to be more.... yellow.

Comment: @Corey: Yes, it's not exactly the effect of a yellow marker, but it's as close as you can get with the built in drawing capabilities. Increasing the alpha value will make the yellow more distinct, but it will make less of the background shine through.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need:

```
    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        using ( var bmp = new Bitmap( 100, 100 ) )
        using ( var g = Graphics.FromImage( bmp ) )
        using ( var ia = new ImageAttributes() )
        {
            // 1. create a sample bitmap
            g.Clear( Color.White );
            var p = Point.Empty;
            foreach ( var color in new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.Gray, Color.LightBlue, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Magenta } )
                using ( var brush = new SolidBrush( color ) )
                {
                    g.DrawString( "Some sample text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, brush, p );
                    p.Offset( 0, 16 );
                }
            // 2. transfer the bitmap on screen
            e.Graphics.DrawImage( bmp, Point.Empty );
            // 3. transfer a part of the bitmap on screen again, this time removing all blue
            ia.SetColorMatrix( new ColorMatrix( new float[][] {
                        new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}} ) );
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(
                bmp,
                new Rectangle( 30, 0, 40, 100 ),
                30, 0, 40, 100,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                ia );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although the above code demonstrates the principle of subtracting the blue, what's missing in this answer is how to adapt this idea to irregular strokes.  Among the answers I posted code that does show how to make irregular strokes look like a marker.

Comment: @Corey Trager: Use the transform to draw a yellowed background, and then use that as a brush to draw your shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `SolidBrush` initialised with a `Color` value with an alpha of less then 255. This should create a semi-transparent brush of the colour you use.